# Family left in prison

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Distinction of common man lost in siege of Paris (10)
>   8. Apprentice and a lead tamer injured a lion of global interest (13)
>   9. Caesar's greeting met with fury, setting initial standards (8)
>   10. Educator Jerry's partner is a rebel without a cause (4)
>   11. Perhaps used to being deposed (6)
>   13. Approach me during the overthrowing of government (4,2)
>   18. Stage street performance's finale quietly (4)
>   20. What a groom may get as outrageous fee told after beginning of ceremony (4,4)
>   22. Much needed helper of a Martian lost behind merchandise (4,9)
>   23. Some bluebell a Don named "deadly plant" (10)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Stylish since Mr. Gere sang in it (7)
>   2. Issues with non-glossy finishes of exterior walls (7)
>   3. Area for star pilot to keep flying gear (7)
>   4. Drawings perhaps from the first parts of Italian Middle Ages (6)
>   5. God seen in empty, old, unfinished tavern (4)
>   6. *The Devil Wears Prada* star spotted in Cannes (4)
>   7. Scottish family left in prison (4)
>   10. Insane to go up a barrier (3)
>   12. From here comes beer and dancing (3)
>   14. Commanded to be ranked according to some criteria (7)
>   15. Not ever playing Liverpool F.C. (7)
>   16. Plant and Page composed a tune containing top intro (7)
>   17. World War II general hiding inside from melancholy (6)
>   18. Expression of frustration with no end in sight (4)
>   19. Regularly engross feelings of self-importance (4)
>   21. I'll say that of Dogs in London, for instance (4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved one of your crosswords completely, jafe! Competed grid as follows:

> [image]

Explanations of individual clues:

> **Across**
>  1. Distinction of common man lost in siege of Paris (10) **COM(PARIS)(-m)ON** [Distinction]
>  8. Apprentice and a lead tamer injured a lion of global interest (13) **INTERN + A + T(amer) + (ALION)*** [of global interest]
>  9. Caesar's greeting met with fury, setting initial standards (8) **AVE + RAGE + (S)etting** [standards]
>  10. Educator Jerry's partner is a rebel without a cause (4) **ddef**
>  11. Perhaps used to being deposed (6) **(USEDTO)*** [deposed]
>  13. Approach me during the overthrowing of government (4,2) **CO(ME)UP** [Approach]
>  18. Stage street performance's finale quietly (4) **ST + (performanc)E + P** [Stage]
>  20. What a groom may get as outrageous fee told after beginning of ceremony (4,4) **C(eremony) + (FEETOLD)*** [What a groom may get]
>  22. Much needed helper of a Martian lost behind merchandise (4,9) **GOODS + (AMARTIAN)*** [Much needed helper]
>  23. Some bluebell a Don named "deadly plant" (10) **_BELLADONNA_** ["deadly plant"]
>
>  **Down**
>  1. Stylish since Mr. Gere sang in it (7) **CHIC + AGO** [Mr. Gere sang in it]
>  2. Issues with non-glossy finishes of exterior walls (7) **MATTE + exterior(R) + wall(S)** [Matters]
>  3. Area for star pilot to keep flying gear (7) **AC(GEAR*)E** [Area]
>  4. Drawings perhaps from the first parts of Italian Middle Ages (6) **I(talian) + M(iddle) + AGES** [Images]
>  5. God seen in empty, old, unfinished tavern (4) **O(-l)D + IN(-n)** [God]
>  6. *The Devil Wears Prada* star spotted in Cannes (4) **_ANNE_** [*The Devil Wears Prada* star]
>  7. Scottish family left in prison (4) **C(L)AN** [Scottish family]
>  10. Insane to go up a barrier (3) **MAD<** [barrier]
>  12. From here comes beer and dancing (3) **ddef**
>  14. Commanded to be ranked according to some criteria (7) **ddef**
>  15. Not ever playing Liverpool F.C. (7) **NOTEVER*** [Liverpool F.C.]
>  16. Plant and Page composed a tune containing top intro (7) **(P+ATUNE+I)*** [Plant]
>  17. World War II general hiding inside from melancholy (6) **_ROMMEL_** [World War II general]
>  18. Expression of frustration with no end in sight (4) **SIGH(-t)** [Expression of frustration]
>  19. Regularly engross feelings of self-importance (4) **E_G_O_S** [feelings of self-importance]
>  21. I'll say that of Dogs in London, for instance (4) **“I’LL”** [that of Dogs in London]

PS As a neutral football fan in this situation, I enjoyed how the method of clue 15 Down would likely be taken very badly in one particular city!

Comment: What's "Caesar's greeting met"?

Comment: @Scratch---Cat "Caesar's greeting" is the Latin word AVE, a greeting word in Ancient Rome, used most famously in connection with Roman Emperors, as in "Ave, Caesar!" traditionally used when meeting the Roman Emperor. You may have come across it in TV, films or the Asterix comics without realising! See [this Wiki page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_Imperator,_morituri_te_salutant) for further examples of usage...